# Trying to add a website on Windows 2019 server where Windows Admin Center is installed

Tags: iis

I was requested to configure IIS for an internal website on Windows 2019 server where Windows Admin Center is installed already. Since 443 was used by Windows Admin Center, I tried to configure a custom port such as 4433 and opened a firewall rule for the port as well as my subnet. The website opens fine locally,  https://mywebsite.com:4433. However, when it is attempted externally, it times out with the following errors:

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

What could be an issue? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try below steps to slove this issue:

1. Check if your internet connection is working properly. Check the status of the network connection and see if it is stable. You can disconnect and connect to the internet to see if the issue is resolved.
2. Disable firewall
   Go to Windows > Settings > Updates and Security > Windows Security > Click Firewall and Network Protection and try to disable
3. Also try clearing your browser's cache and see if the issue is resolved